# xypic: 2-Cell Triangle Identities

Tags: lyx, xy-pic, tikz-cd

I would like to typeset, using `xypic`, the triangle identities from the definition of adjoint functors in category theory. My problem is with creating the double arrow connecting the hypotenuse and the opposite corner.

[image]

Here's the (completely trivial) part I can do myself, which is everything but the double arrows:
`\xymatrix{
    C\ar[r]^{F}\ar[dr]_{1_{C}} & D\ar[d]^{G} &  & D\ar[dr]^{1_{D}}\ar[d]_{G}\\
    & C &  & C\ar[r]_{F} & D
}`

There is supposedly a way of creating such "pasting diagrams" in `xypic`, but I haven't found any clear instructions anywhere; I know the command `\compositemap` is somehow involved but I could not figure out how to use it.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See pg 12 http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf or pg 43 http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyrefer.pdf

Comment: @Thruston, I have no minimal working example. I have no idea how to make the diagrams I want

Comment: @Sigur I had seen those sources before you posted, but they did not help me at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not use `xy` anymore, as it is not that easy and powerful as [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd). I hope, this solution will help you as well:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}    
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
C \arrow{r}{F} \arrow[""{name=foo}]{dr}[swap]{1_C} & D \arrow{d}{G} \arrow[Rightarrow, from=foo, swap, near start, "\eta"]& D \arrow{d}[swap]{G} \arrow[""{name=bar, below}]{dr}{1_D} & \\
& C & C \arrow{r}[swap]{F} \arrow[Rightarrow, to=bar, swap, near start, "\varepsilon"] & D
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As you wished, here is a solution with `xy`. It is quite hacky. Using the examples mentioned by Sigur would be better, I guess. But as `xy` is able to manage empty matrix entries, I used this in order to point arrows to where I want. The double amount of matrix nodes is necessary though.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
,all
%,cmtip % recommended, but I do not know how to get it to work for the double arrow
]{xy}

\begin{document}    
\[\xymatrix@R=4mm @C=4mm{ 
    C\ar[rr]^{F} \ar[ddrr]_{1_{C}} & & D \ar[dd]^{G} & & D \ar[ddrr]^{1_{D}} \ar[dd]_{G} & & \\ 
    &\ar@2{->}[ur]_{\eta} & & & & & \\
    & & C & & C \ar@2{->}[ur]_{\varepsilon} \ar[rr]_{F} & & D 
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your `tikz` solution, but I would also much like an `xy` solution as it is a lot easier to use in LyX.

Comment: @Exterior You can just copy my code in to your TeX-File. Even in LyX. As you have not even provided one single letter of code, it is not very likely to get help for this (quite hard in `xy`, if you are interested). This is not a "we-code-for-free"-page. Sorry, but I down-voted your question until it gets some improvement by you.

Comment: I understand. I can of course put up the code for the triangles, but that's really pretty trivial in `xypic` and the problem is entirely with the 2-arrows. At any rate, I'll add the code for the triangles.

Comment: @Exterior See my update

Answer (score 6):

Another `xy-pic` solution with a different approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{ 
  C\ar[r]^{F}\ar[dr]_{1_{C}} & D\ar[d]^{G}\ar@{<=}[dl]+<22pt>^>>>{\eta} & & D\ar[dr]^{1_{D}}\ar[d]_{G}                      & \\ 
                             & C                                        & & C\ar[r]_{F}\ar@{=>}[ur]-<22pt>_>>>{\varepsilon} & D 
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: +1. Still though, I would like to see the "right" answer using `\compositemap`.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at the same thing and tried to use the `2cell` feature in `xy-pic`. After reading the [reference manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xypic/xyrefer.pdf), I think the "right" solution is the following

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\UseAllTwocells

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{C\drtwocell\omit{^<-2>\eta}\ar_{1_C}[dr]\ar^F[r]&D\ar^G[d]&
D\drtwocell\omit{^<2>\varepsilon}\ar^{1_D}[dr]\ar_G[d]&\\
&C&C\ar_F[r]&D}
\]
\end{document}
```

The code reads as `\drtwocell\omit{^<-2>\eta}`, where `\omit` says we will omit the two curved arrows, the `^` specifies the direction of the 2-cell, and `<-2>` nudges the label (otherwise it will be at the center point).

Output:

[image]

There is a problem: you *cannot* specify which side the label is on with respect to the 2-cell. It seems that this is not implemented, so perhaps this is the best we can do without some other hacks.