# Typesetting triangular 2cells in xypic

Tags: xy-pic

I would like to typeset the diagram below in `xypic`.

[image]

Unforunately, I have no idea how to do this, and I find it impossible to figure out how to actually use the `2cell` extension for `xypic`.

The best I'm managing is:

[image]

Given by

```
\documentclass[oneside,american,oldfontcommands,all,cmtip]{memoir}
\usepackage{xy}
\xyoption{2cell}
\UseAllTwocells

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{\cdot\ar[dr]\\
& \cdot\ulcompositemap<4.8>
}
\]

\end{document}
```

I also don't know how to adapt the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216305/96646). Particularly, the answers resolve the 2cell on the right, but the arrow is parallel to the southwest arrow, so I can't resolve the 2cell on the left.

Comment: Please provide a complete compilable minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)) showing everything you got so far.

Answer (score 2):

An example with `tikz-cd` intead of `xymatrix`. It is more easy.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\rin}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\Rightarrow$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & \cdot \arrow[ld, "\rin"] \arrow[d] \arrow[rd, "\rin"'] &  \\
\cdot \arrow[r] & \cdot \arrow[r] & \cdot
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `xy` and `txfonts` for arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,american,oldfontcommands,all,cmtip]{memoir}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath,txfonts}

\begin{document}

\[ 
\xymatrix{ & \bullet \ar[dl] \ar[d] \ar[dr] & \\
\bullet \ar[r] & \bullet \ar[r] \ar@{}[lu]|(.25){\Nearrow} \ar@{}[ru]|(.25){\Nearrow}&  \bullet
}
\]

\end{document}
```

**Update:** Here is a solution using the `graphicx` to rotate the standard `\Rightarrow` (so no `txfonts` required as above).

```
\documentclass[oneside,american,oldfontcommands,all,cmtip]{memoir}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\implication}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\Rightarrow$}}

\begin{document}

\[ 
\xymatrix{ & \bullet \ar[dl] \ar[d] \ar[dr] & \\
\bullet \ar[r] & \bullet \ar[r] \ar@{}[lu]|(.25){\implication} \ar@{}[ru]|(.25){\implication}&  \bullet
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]